# Node.jsによるファイル書き込み時の特殊文字処理について

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, 正規表現

Latexエディターを制作しており、そこでファイル書き込み処理に苦戦しているのでご教授お願いしたいです。
ユーザーが入力したテキストデータをjson形式でサーバーにpost送信し、サーバー側でtexファイルを作成するときにテキストデータに含まれる特殊文字`\\`を`\`に変換して.texファイルに書き込みたいです。

postするjsonデータの一部(見やすいように改行しております)

```
"\\documentclass{jsarticle}\n
\\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}\n
\\setlength{\\textheight}{24cm}\n
\\setlength{\\topmargin}{-1.5cm}\n
\\setlength{\\textwidth}{17cm}\n
\\setlength{\\oddsidemargin}{-.5cm}\n
\\usepackage{here}\n
......
```

サーバー側で作成した.texファイル

```
"\\documentclass{jsarticle}
\\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\\setlength{\\textheight}{24cm}
\\setlength{\\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\\setlength{\\textwidth}{17cm}
\\setlength{\\oddsidemargin}{-.5cm}
\\usepackage{here}
....
```

作成したtexファイルに上記のような`\\`の書き込みになってしまい、本来のlatexの書き方と違ってきます......。

理想は以下のようtexファイルに書き込みたいです。

```
"\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5cm}
\usepackage{here}
....
```

現在サーバー側でデータを受け取り、ファイル作成している処理コードは以下です。

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify(req.body.msg);
  console.log(jsonData);
  var arr = jsonData.split(/\\n/);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
    //arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\\/g, '');
    fs.appendFileSync('sample.tex', arr[i] + '\n', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

msgにすべてのテキストデータが入っています。うまくできないのでコメントアウトしております。
なんとかtexファイルに`\`を書き込むことはできないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします<(_ _)>

**＜追記＞**
エディターでは以下のように入力しています。

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5cm}
\usepackage{here}
....
```

クライアント側で以下のコードで、テキストデータを送信しております。
＊Aceを使いエディターを作成しております。

```
$('#save').click(function(e) {
      //alert(editor.getValue());
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/editor',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'msg': editor.getValue()},
        dataType: 'json'
      });
    });
```

editor.getValue()に入力されたデータが入っており、中身は以下のようになっております。

```
"\\documentclass{jsarticle}
\\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\\setlength{\\textheight}{24cm}
\\setlength{\\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\\setlength{\\textwidth}{17cm}
\\setlength{\\oddsidemargin}{-.5cm}
\\usepackage{here}
......"
```

これをそのままjsonデータとして送信しているので、`\\`がついたままtexファイルを作成されるのだと思っております。

Answer (score 0):

> サーバー側でtexファイルを作成する

とのことですが、このtexファイルは「ユーザーの入力したものをそのままファイルとして保存したい」ということで間違いないでしょうか。

そして、ユーザーの入力したものがそのままJSON形式で`req.body.msg`に入っているのであれば、`JSON.parse`を用いることで、JSON形式の文字列からユーザーが入力した元々の文字列を復元することができます。

つまり、これだけでいいのではないかと思います。

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(req.body.msg);
// jsonDataにユーザーが入力した文字列が入っている
console.log(jsonData);

fs.writeFileSync('sample.tex', jsonData, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

ただし、実際にはユーザーがJSON形式ではない変なデータを送ってきて`JSON.parse`でエラーが発生したり`JSON.parse`の結果が文字列でない可能性もありますので、その対処も必要となります。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
先程のコードを試しましたが、結果は変わらないようです。
より詳しく現状をお伝えするために、質問内容に追記しましたのでご確認お願いします<(_ _)>

Comment: texファイル保存については、その通りでございます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。可能ならサーバー側のコードの全体を追記いただけないでしょうか？　`express`をお使いではないかと推測しておりますが、どのように`express`が設定されているかを知りたいです。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
先程、問題を解決することができました。
ご協力して頂きありがとうございます<(_ _)>